# Animate component by clicking a different component

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I am building an online store and I want to animate the cart logo whenever someone clicks on the add to cart button.

The add to cart button is part of the collection item component and the cart icon is a different component inside the header. They are not connected to each other.

I have the css animation but I need help connecting between the different components.

I'm adding code snippets of the relevant components:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";

import { toggleCartHidden } from "../../redux/cart/cart.actions";
import { selectCartItemsCount } from "../../redux/cart/cart.selectors";

import {
  CartContainer,
  ShoppingIcon,
  ItemCountContainer
} from "./cart-icon.styles";

const CartIcon = ({ toggleCartHidden, itemCount }) => (
  <div className="hvr-buzz-out">
    <CartContainer onClick={toggleCartHidden}>
      <ShoppingIcon />
      <ItemCountContainer>{itemCount}</ItemCountContainer>
    </CartContainer>
  </div>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  toggleCartHidden: () => dispatch(toggleCartHidden())
});

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  itemCount: selectCartItemsCount
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CartIcon);
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { addItem } from '../../redux/cart/cart.actions';

import {
  CollectionItemContainer,
  CollectionFooterContainer,
  AddButton,
  BackgroundImage,
  NameContainer,
  PriceContainer
} from './collection-item.styles';

const CollectionItem = ({ item, addItem }) => {
  const { name, price, imageUrl } = item;

  return (
    <CollectionItemContainer>
      <BackgroundImage className='image' imageUrl={imageUrl} />
      <CollectionFooterContainer>
        <NameContainer>{name}</NameContainer>
        <PriceContainer>{price}&#8362;</PriceContainer>
      </CollectionFooterContainer>
      <AddButton onClick={() => addItem(item)} inverted>
        Add to cart
      </AddButton>
    </CollectionItemContainer>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addItem: item => dispatch(addItem(item))
});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CollectionItem);
```

How this can be done?

BTW the containers are just styled components.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The redux store is the connection, just animate when item count changes.

Comment: But how? 
Change class name when store is updated?

Comment: See answer. I don't know if this is best practice but it has worked for me before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

someOtherClass will be added on itemCount change, and removed after animation is complete. If keyframe animation, use onAnimationEnd instead of onTransitionEnd

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

...

export const CartIcon = ({ toggleCartHidden , itemCount }) => {
  const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);
  const isMounting = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounting.current) { //No animation on initial mount
      isMounting.current = false; 
    } else {
      setAnimate(true); // Set animate to true
    }
  }, [itemCount]); //Only run useEffect if itemCount has changed

  const className = `hvr-buzz-out${animate ? ' classForAnimate' : ''}`
  return (
    <div className={className} onTransitionEnd={() => setAnimate(false)}>
      <CartContainer onClick={toggleCartHidden} >
        <ShoppingIcon />
        <ItemCountContainer>{itemCount}</ItemCountContainer>
      </CartContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css could be something like

```
.hvr-buzz-outate {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
.classForAnimate {
  background-color: blue;
}
```